# Роль организации GNU

Tags: c++, unix, gdb, gnu

Не могу понять роль организации GNU. Переводится как некий проект ***not Unix. Эм...ну если not Unix, то почему тогда их проект gdb это отладчик под Unix системы?

Comment: Название такое, т.к. по дизайну очень походил на Unix, но был за бесплатное ПО. А на заре эпохи Unix был очень популярен.

Comment: @Unick не бесплатное, а открытое/свободное

Comment: @insolor я основывался на этом:  chosen because GNU's design is Unix-like, but differs from Unix by being free software and containing no Unix code. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU)

Comment: @Unick с английского free переводится как свободный или как бесплатный. В данном случае имеется в виду свобода (как free speech - свобода слова), а не бесплатность (как free beer).

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: @Unick, вот кстати откуда взята аналогия про free speech и free beer: [What is free software?](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) `"To understand the concept, you should think of “free” as in “free speech,” not as in “free beer”"`

Comment: Почитайте книжку -- [Хакеры: Герои компьютерной революции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B:_%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). Не прямо по теме вопроса, но увлекательно описаны события в результате которых появились FSF и GNU. / Да и остальные истории весьма интересны

Comment: А по теме,  *GNU* это акроним фразы *GNU Not Unix*. Одно из толкований происхождения --  это шутка о бесконечной начальной рекурсии. Почему **не UNIX**? Ответ простой -- в отличии от настоящего  UNIX® вы можете свободно (imho все же *почти* свободно) им пользоваться

Comment: Еще про [историю свободного программного обеспечения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)  есть хорошая статья в вике (с множеством ссылок)

Comment: *imho все же **почти** свободно* — ох, любит avp проприетарщиков!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проект GNU (англ. The GNU Project) — проект по разработке свободного программного обеспечения (СПО), является результатом сотрудничества множества отдельных проектов. Проект был запущен программистом и сторонником СПО Ричардом Столлманом 27 сентября 1983 года в Массачусетском технологическом институте. Изначальной целью проекта было «разработать достаточно свободного программного обеспечения, чтобы можно было обойтись без программного обеспечения, которое не является свободным».

Текущая работа проекта GNU включает в себя разработку программного обеспечения, повышение осведомлённости, проведение политических кампаний и раздачу новых материалов.

Пожалуй, в контексте твоего вопроса, интереснее всего фраза

> является результатом сотрудничества множества отдельных проектов

[Манифест](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/philosophy.html)

[Лицензии](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/licenses.html)

[Программы](http://www.gnu.org/software/software.html). Уверен, тебя заинтересует список.

---

Философию происходящего в этом проекте хорошо иллюстрирует существование нежно мною любимой [LibreJS](http://www.gnu.org/software/librejs/).

> дополнение к Firefox, позволяющее отказаться от
>   выполнения несвободного JavaScript-кода. По мнению Ричарда Столлмана,
>   проблема с JavaScript состоит в том, что код загружается без ведома
>   пользователя, не давая возможности оценить степень его свободности
>   перед загрузкой и воспрепятствовать выполнению проприетарного
>   JavaScript-кода. Определение применяемой в JavaScript-коде лицензии
>   производится через указание на сайте специальных меток или через
>   анализ наличия упоминания лицензии в комментариях к коду. Кроме того,
>   по умолчанию допускается выполнение тривиального JavaScript-кода,
>   известных библиотек и кода с сайтов, занесённых пользователем в белый
>   список.

Answer (score 2):

#### Про название.

В старом *nix-мире обычной практикой было, что кто-то брал какую-то программу, немного изменял её или писал совместимую, но немного отличающуюся. В итоге новую программу нужно как-то было называть. Обычно или добавлялось пару букв, характеризующих улучшение по этой схеме именования до сих пор сохранились, например, `syslog-ng`, `aircrack-ng` (Next Generation), `vim` (Vi IMproved), или имя автора: `ksh` (Korn SHell). За отсутствием повсеместного доступа к интернету и за тем фактом что написание софта под себя было нормой таких вариантов накапливались десятки и в каждой сети были свои.

В 80-е был распространён редактор [TECO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Editor_and_Corrector) (тико) и по аналогии свои редакторы многие <s>программисты</s> хакеры называли свои поделия такой-то-тико и сякой-то-тико, но один умный хакер решил пошутить и назвал свой редактор tint (Tint Is Not Teco). Шутка многим пришлась по вкусу и отчасти даже стала традицией именования.

Ричард Мэттью Столлманом (rms) — один из тех толстых весёлых парней, кто в принципе любит пошутить и кому эта шутка в том числе нравилась. Когда он начал искать имя для своей свободной UNIX-подобной операционной системы он решил придерживаться шаблона «что-то не UNIX», но ни один из 26 возможных вариантов «?INU» не являлся словом и название получалось не такое уж интересное. В итоге волевым решением он сократил его на одну букву и получил классическое «GNU's Not Unix», которое с одной стороны следовало традиции, а с другой имело за собой шлейф вторых прочтений, среди которых «не UNIX от GNU» и «не UNIX от гну» итп.

*Вольный пересказ [лекции](https://www.gnu.org/pronunciation/pronunciation.html) самого rms.*

Comment: они там вообще любят повеселиться https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=48559